# Spark SQL: IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS, expected: file:///

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I try to put data in Hive table via Spark SQL terminal.

I created table based on Avro Schema .avsc :

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.url'='file:///C:/some_dir/table_schema.avsc');
```

Then I try to load data from Avro file which stored in HDFS:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://localhost:9000/data/test_table.avro' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test_table;
```

I get an error:

```
Error in query: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:9000/data/test_table.avro, expected: file:///;
```

When I try to load from local file system it works.

Also my **core-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
        <final>true</final>
        <description>NameNode URI</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

How to load data from files which stored in HDFS?

Comment: try `LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs:///localhost:9000/data/test_table.avro' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test_table;`

Comment: @ramesh-maharjan ava.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/localhost:9000/data/test_table.avro

Comment: what did you put in your core-site.xml?

Comment: @ramesh-maharjan <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
        <final>true</final>
        <description>NameNode URI</description>
    </property>

Comment: why don''t you try with scala ? more info https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/spark_avro.html

Comment: I just would like to figure out this way. I know that way works.. probably forgot some small detail in the settings..